# Query is not working in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

When I use this query I found an error like this

> `#`1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'select table1.name , table2.age from table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON
>   table1.name = t' at line 1

I have thee tables

```
table1 contain name an id fields
table2 contain id, name an age fields
table3 contain name age ane id field
```

take the name from table 1 then get the age from table2 and insert that values in table3

I'm using query

```
INSERT INTO table3 (name,age) values (select table1.name , table2.age from table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.name )
```

but its not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the `VALUES` keyword when inserting with a subquery.

```
INSERT INTO table3 (name,age) select table1.name , table2.age from table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.name
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove "VALUES", it's not needen when you do INSERT... SELECT

Answer (score -2):

Wrong SQL:
It should be

```
select table1.name , table2.age from table1 INNER JOIN table2 WHERE table1.name = t
```

Comment: Actually using `ON` is the right thing to do. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: His select syntax looks OK to me. Yours works too, but ON clause is more clear

Comment: `ON` is used in `join`, but I remember it should be used between two tables. For example, `ON table1.category_id = table2.id`. When the condition just in one table, it should be use `WHERE`. For example, `SELECT p1.name, p2.name FROM table1 p1 JOIN table2 p2 ON p1.category_id = p2.id WHERE p1.id > 50`

Comment: @M.I.T. It means nothing ;) In fact my answer is not correct. When I answer it ,I *DO* not see the last SQL and answer it with my experience, and I think it should mislead you in some way.